# using connectors to read from office365 excel file

Tags: .net, office365connectors

I've been reading a lot about connectors and I'm trying to develop a .net application that is able to read data from an excel file in office 365 much like power apps such as power automation. The problem is in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/use-custom-connector-logic-apps I only find ways to connect a file using azure or power apps. How can I read data from an office 365 file using my own .net application?

Comment: You don't need connectors. All files are accessible by a URL. You can download the file with just `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync` or `HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync`. You'll still have to use a library like ExcelDataReader or EPPlus to open and process the file.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but one thing I forgot to add is that in the future I need to re-read the file if any user has changed it. I can use the connector's triggers to notify my application that something has changed. If I use the URL I'll have to poll the file every once in a while, and I would like to avoid it